# How to calculate the difference in height between two divs

Tags: javascript, css

I have a tree with conditional questions and answers and I would like to join two branches (as in the attached picture, in red)

[image]

I've tried a lot of things but I can't do it, it's a recursive tree.
Maybe something like this ?

```
var result = $("#myDiv").height();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').offsetHeight
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do calculations with `clientHeight` and `offsetHeight`, but those are relative to the parent elements, which makes it tricky to do calculations with it when having nested tree structures.

The method `element.getBoundingClientRect()` is very handy and powerful for these kind of calculations. It gives you back `left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom`, `width`, and `height` relative to the viewport.

```js
document.getElementById('myDiv').getBoundingClientRect()
```

See docs on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Answer (score 1):

HTMLElement object has these 3 kinds of height atributes that can be useful in the calculation of the height of an element -

1. **clientHeight** (Only the inner content, without padding and border)
2. **offsetHeight** (content + padding + border)
3. **scrollHeight** (Minimum height occupied including content, padding, border, margin)

**Here is a working example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.my-div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 25px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDIV" class="my-div"></div>
<p id="output"></p>

<script>
  var element = document.getElementById("myDIV")
  
  var output = ("clientHeight = " + element.clientHeight + " px<br>")
  output += ("offsetHeight = " + element.offsetHeight + " px<br>")
  output += ("scrollHeight = " + element.scrollHeight + " px<br>")
  
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image]

**More information:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use like this
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1" style="border:1px solid green;">
    Bulbul Sarker <br>  
    Bulbul Sarker <br>  
    Bulbul Sarker <br>  
    Bulbul Sarker <br>  
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="div2" style="border:1px solid red">
    Bulbul
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    var div1 = document.getElementById('div1').offsetHeight;
    var div2 = document.getElementById('div2').offsetHeight;

    console.log('div1', div1);
    console.log('div3', div2);
    
    var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
    var height = div1.offsetHeight;
    var width = div1.offsetWidth;

    console.log('height = ',height);
    console.log('width = ',width);

</script>
```